# Fix Broken Launcher on Soft-Bricked Device

Tags: launcher, motorola-moto-g2

I recently tried to remove the Google search bar on my homescreen using [this](http://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/how-remove-google-search-bar-on-android-without-root-3599104/) tutorial by disabling the Google Search app in settings. It turns out I was using the Google Now launcher, and so when I rebooted the launcher broke and sent me into some kind of recovery mode (not the proper android recovery mode.) It went through the booting animation, but then just came up with an alert saying 'Optimising Apps: 1/150', which cycled through each app and 'optimised' it. Upon completion, a black screen came up and the phone rebooted itself.

I'm using an unrooted Moto G2 which had Marshmallow running on it. I'm wondering how to reinstall my OS or otherwise restore my device; I don't care about data as it is backed up.

Any ideas how to fix/reinstall my Android installation?

Comment: If all you did was disabling the Google App then it shouldn't have caused such havoc - try initiating a factory reset from fastboot first.

Comment: Would that be the 'Factory' option in the fastboot menu that I get when pressing Power+VolDown? If so, that just does a 'normal' powerup which gets stuck in a bootloop like turning the device on normally.

Comment: Yeah I meant that. If that doesn't work out for you, you'd have to flash a factory image, also via fastboot. For that you'll need to know your exact model number (should be on the fastboot screen as "XT10xx".

Comment: @AndyYan Maybe OP removed the launcher? Does their model come with Google Now?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman He did explicitly say it was a *bootloop*, whereas a removed launcher should at least present a black screen after the boot animation...

Comment: @AndyYan Correct. I was just "checking if you were paying attention", is all. *cough*

Comment: @AndyYan After the boot animation and after a modal appears saying 'Optimising Apps', which runs for a few minutes, it briefly comes up with a black screen before rebooting.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman My phone does use the default launcher which I believe is Google Now. I thought I turned it off in settings, but I must've only disabled the Google Now feed.

Comment: @AndyYan I just visited the link OP posted, and they indeed suggest to disable Google Now. Given the additional info Tobsta mentioned, it does quite seem a missing launcher's symptom.

Comment: @Tobsta Could you update your question with these findings, please? Also, did you not install another launcher as suggested in your link?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Silly me, I wasn't thinking clearly when I first asked the question. I was in a hurry at the time and I misread the article, assuming that installing a different launcher was a separate solution. I'll update the question now.

Comment: Ok, I've worked out how to factory reset my device. It seems there are two recovery menus - one when you press Power+VolDown and other when you select the 'Recovery' option in the aforementioned menu (which shows a dead android saying "No Command"), hold the power button and then tap the volume down button. Both menus have a factory reset option, but only the latter (as far as I know) works.
Now that I know my device is recoverable, is there any way for me to avoid having to factory reset for convenience?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question, thanks for the help.

To get into recovery mode on my Moto G2, I first went into the bootloader by force shutting down the bootlooping device (hold power until it turns off) and then pressing Power and Volume Down at the same time for 2-5 seconds. I then selected 'Recovery', which came up with the boot animation and then a dead android with the words 'No Command' written above. I then pressed Power for 5-6 seconds and tapped the Volume Down button, which took me to the recovery mode menu.

I then selected the option 'Wipe data/factory reset' and selected 'Userdata only'. Once it wiped that, I rebooted and waited ~10mins at the booting animation before it took me through the Android setup wizard. All of my data was restored through Google Drive and Google Photos, even stuff like the order in which apps were displayed on my homescreen.